# Turning a div that includes a ul with a hidden li list from HTM to JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, createelement

SO I'm practicing my JS skills and would like to turn my HTML completely or almost completely into JS. I would like to focus on creating these elements and making them work.

```js
var main = function() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.recipePicContainer').click(function () {
                $(this).next('.recipes').toggle("slow").toggleClass('selected');
            });
        });
    };
    $(document).ready(main);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainContainer col-md-12 col-xs-12">
    
        <div class="checkBoxes">
            <span class="recipePicContainer">
                <img class="recipe" src="../images/grasshopper-cocktail.jpg" alt="Cocktail">
                <div>Cocktail</div>
            </span>
            <ul class="recipes">
               <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 1</li>
               <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 2</li>
               <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 3</li>
               <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 4</li>
               <li class="instructions">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, here's the checkbox part figured out:

```
 $('<input type="checkbox" value="1" />').prependTo(".ingredients");
```

still need some help with the loop.
anyone?